# Implement Tapatalk image upload in Perl

Tags: perl, postgresql, file-upload, upload, httprequest

I am writing a [Tapatalk](https://tapatalk.com/) plugin using Perl. I have gone through Tapatalk documentation to upload images from tapatalk app  https://tapatalk.com/api/api_section.php?id=8#upload.php

As per documentation, I have a upload.cgi at the root of plugin directory which is called when any image upload tried from tapatalk app. I have get method name, forumid, attachment image name in upload.cgi.

But Now I am confuse how to handle all to display uploaded image in tapatalk app after successful upload.  How input parameters of upload.cgi will be handled. How upload details will be posted to upload.cgi

I have posted form details like below

```
my $req = POST '$upload_url',
       Content_Type => 'form-data',      
       Content      => [ method_name => 'upload_attach',
                         forum_id => $forumid,
                         "attachment[]"   => [
                                undef,
                                $filename,
                                'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg',                                
                        ],
                       ];

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $ua->request($req);
```

But I have not get it work. please help me, If anyone have done before. If you have sample code regarding image upload, please share it.

Comment: Please post your whole script and make sure you have turned on error checking with `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of the script. Have you checked what response you get from sending the request?

Comment: Potential bug:  Your url variable is in single quotes and won't be interpolated `'$upload_url'`.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, your script is doing nothing because `$req` is set to this code melange that Perl does not know how to interpret:

```
my $req = POST '$upload_url',
       Content_Type => 'form-data',      
       Content      => [ method_name => 'upload_attach',
                         forum_id => $forumid,
                         "attachment[]"   => [
                                undef,
                                $filename,
                                'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg',                                
                        ],
                       ];
```

If you want to use `$ua->request()`, you need to create a `HTTP::Request` object. From the docs for [`LWP::UserAgent`](http://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ua-request-request) `request`:

> `$ua->request( $request )`
>
> This method will dispatch the given `$request` object. Normally this will be an instance of the [`HTTP::Request`](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request) class, but any object with a similar interface will do. The return value is a response object. See [`HTTP::Request`](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request) and [`HTTP::Response`](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response) for a description of the interface provided by these classes.

From the docs for [`HTTP::Request`](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request):

> `$r = HTTP::Request->new( $method, $uri, $header, $content )`
>
> Constructs a new [`HTTP::Request`](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request) object describing a request on the object `$uri` using method `$method`. The `$method` argument must be a string. The `$uri` argument can be either a string, or a reference to a URI object. The optional `$header` argument should be a reference to an `HTTP::Headers` object or a plain array reference of key/value pairs. The optional `$content` argument should be a string of bytes.

So, reformatting your request, we get the following:

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new('POST', $upload_url,
    [ Content_Type => 'form-data' ],
      Content      => [
        method_name => 'upload_attach',
        forum_id => $forumid,
        "attachment[]"   => [
            undef,
            'this.jpg',
            'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg',
        ],
    ]);
```

Plug that all into a script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $upload_url = 'http://example.com';
my $forum_id = '1a2b3c4d5e';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $req = HTTP::Request->new('POST', $upload_url,
    [ Content_Type => 'form-data' ],
      Content      => [
        method_name => 'upload_attach',
        forum_id => $forum_id,
        "attachment[]"   => [
            undef,
            'this.jpg',
            'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg',
        ],
    ]);

my $response = $ua->request($req);
if ($response->is_success) {
    # do whatever with $response->decoded_content
}
else {
    print STDERR "POST failed: " . $response->status_line . "\n";
}
```

You can see the raw HTTP response using `$response->as_string`.

Hope that helps a little!